# ¿Qué tener en cuenta en R para construir un ejemplo reproducible?

Tags: r

Ya sea a la hora de plantear una pregunta en este sitio o que debamos compartir un ejemplo con algún colega, ¿Que elementos debemos tener en cuenta, para asegurar la reproducibilidad del ejemplo? (información, datos, estructuras, etc.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vamos a traducir y adaptar un poco la [excelente respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?noredirect=1&lq=1) de **Joris Meys** en el sitio en ingles.

Un buen ejemplo mínimo y reproducible debería constar de los siguientes elementos:

- un conjunto de datos mínimo, necesario para reproducir el error o entender la consulta
- el código mínimo ejecutable necesario para reproducir el error o entender la consulta, que puede ejecutarse con el conjunto de datos dado.
- la información necesaria sobre los paquetes utilizados, la versión R y el sistema en el que se ejecuta.
- en el caso de procesos aleatorios, una semilla (la que normalmente se establece por **`set.seed()`**)

A menudo resulta útil examinar los ejemplos de los archivos de ayuda de las funciones utilizadas. En general, todo el código que allí se da, cumple con los requisitos de un ejemplo mínimo reproducible: se proporcionan datos, se proporciona un código mínimo y todo es ejecutable.

### Producción de un conjunto de datos mínimo

Para la mayoría de los casos, esto se puede lograr fácilmente proporcionando el objeto **`vector/dataframe/matrix/etc`** con algunos valores de ejemplo. O bien se puede indicar alguno de los **`datasets`** ya incorporados, que se suministran con la mayoría de los paquetes. Se puede ver una lista completa de los conjuntos de datos incorporados con el comando: **`library(help = "datasets")`**. Existe una breve descripción de cada conjunto de datos y se puede obtener más información, por ejemplo, haciendo **`?mtcars`** dónde **`mtcars`** es uno de los datasets de la lista. Otros paquetes pueden contener conjuntos de datos adicionales.

Crear un **`vector`** es fácil. A veces es necesario añadir algo de aleatoriedad, y hay un número entero de funciones para hacer eso. `sample()` puede aleatorizar un **`vector`**, o dar un **`vector`** aleatorio con sólo unos pocos valores. **`letters`** es un vector útil que contiene el alfabeto, éste se puede utilizar para construir factores.

Algunos ejemplos:

- valores aleatorios: **`x <- rnorm(10)`** para distribución normal, **`x <- runif (10)`** para distribución uniforme,...
- una permutación de algunos valores: **`x <- sample(1:10)`** para el vector **`1:10`** en orden aleatorio.
- un factor aleatorio: **`x <- sample(letters[1:4], 20, replace = TRUE)`**

Para las matrices, se puede utilizar **`matrix()`**, por ejemplo:

- **`matrix(1:10, ncol = 2)`**

La creación de **`dataframes`** se puede realizar usando **`data.frame()`**. Prestar atención en la creación, no hacer un **`dataframe`** demasiado complicado, no agregar variables que no se vayan a usar.

Un ejemplo:

```
Data <- data.frame(
    X = sample(1:10),
    Y = sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE)
)
```

En algunos casos, resulta necesario mantener los formatos específicos de cada variable/columna. Para estos, se puede utilizar cualquiera de las funciones proporcionadas como **`<as.AlgunTipo>`** como: **`as.factor`**, **`as.Date`**, **`as.xts`**, etc.

### Copiar datos propios

Si usted tiene algunos datos que serían demasiado difíciles de construir usando estos métodos, o son necesarios para poder comprender un problema (Por ej: para determinar un problema de conversión de un fecha desde una cadena hay que "ver" el formato del dato real, no un ejemplo que seguramente este correcto), entonces siempre podrá hacer un subconjunto de sus datos originales, usando por ejemplo **`head()`**, **`subset()`** o los índices. Entonces puede utilizar **`dput()`** para darnos algo que pueda ser puesto en R inmediatamente:

```
> dput(head(iris,4))
structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6), Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 
3, 3.2, 3.1), Petal.Length = c(1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5), Petal.Width = c(0.2, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.2), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("setosa", 
"versicolor", "virginica"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Sepal.Length", 
"Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species"), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")
```

En algunos casos, un **`dataframe`** puede tener muchísimos valores que sean manejados como Factores, haciendo un **`subset`** o un **`head`** obtenemos una muestra más chica, pero de todas formas estaríamos trasladando los Factores/niveles que no estamos usando en esta muestra. Lo que podemos hacer estos casos es eliminar los Levels/niveles que no se estén utilizando en la muestra. Usando **`droplevels()`**, por ejemplo:

```
> dput(droplevels(head(iris, 4)))
structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6), Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 
3, 3.2, 3.1), Petal.Length = c(1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5), Petal.Width = c(0.2, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.2), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "setosa",
class = "factor")), .Names = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", 
"Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species"), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Notese que ahora **`Species`** tiene un solo nivel **`.Label = "setosa"`** por que efectivamente solo tenemos estos en la muestra: **`Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)`**

Otra advertencia para dput es que no funcionará para los datos indexados **`data.table`** o para **`tbl_df`** (clase **`grouped_df`** de **`dplyr`**). Para esto casos se puede convertir el objeto a un **`dataframe`** común antes de compartirlo: **`dput(as.data.frame(my_data))`**.

En el peor de los casos, usted puede dar una representación textual que eventualmente podría ser leída mediante **`read.table()`**:

```
zz <- "Sepal. Longitud Sepal. Anchura Ancho Petal. Longitud Petal. Anchura Especie
1 5,1 3,5 1,4 0,2 setosa
2 4,9 3,0 1,4 0,2 setosa
3 4,7 3,2 1,3 0,2 setosa
4 4,6 3,1 1,5 0,2 setosa
5 5,0 3,6 1,4 0,2 setosa
6 5,4 3,9 1,7 0,4 setosa"

Data <- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)
```

Eventualmente podría pasar que los datos sean tales que resulte impracticable compartirlos de las formas mencionadas, evalué entonces usar algún servicio, Por ej. hasta 0.5mb podría usarse [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/): **`d <- read.table("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=m1ZJuKLH")`** o bien algún otro. Recuerde que puede salvar cualquier objeto con **`write(df, "archivo.Rda")`** y luego cargarlo con **`load("archivo.Rda")`**.

Si de cualquier forma no es posible compartir datos, minímamente debiéramos poder informar estructura y clase de los objetos, para eso algunas de estas rutinas suelen aportar información relevante:

```
dim(df)
class(df)
typeof(df)
attributes(df)
length(df)
head(str(df))
```

### Compartiendo el código mínimo

Esta debería ser la parte fácil, pero a menudo no lo es. Lo que no deberías hacer, es:

- añadir todo tipo de conversiones de datos. Asegúrese de que los datos suministrados estén ya en el formato correcto (a menos que ese sea el problema, por supuesto)
- copiar-pegar una función entera o la parte de código que da error. Primero trate de localizar qué líneas exactamente dan en el error. La mayoría de las veces descubrirás cuál es tu problema.

Lo que debería hacer, es:

- añadir una explicación simple y concisa de lo que hace su código, lo que se espera que haga y lo que realmente hace. En el caso que el resultado sean datos, añadir una muestra de como debieran ser estos es mucho más claro que cualquier explicación que pueda hacer.
- añadir los paquetes que se deben usar si se usa alguno. Ej: **`library("randomForest")`** o **`require("ggplot")`**.
- si abre conexiones o hace archivos, añada algún código para cerrarlos o borre los archivos al finalizar (usando **`unlink()`**)
- si cambia las opciones, asegúrese de que el código contiene una instrucción para revertirlas a las originales. (por ejemplo: **`op <- par(mfrow=c (1,2))... algún código... par(op)`**)
- Nombres de variables concisas y explicativas, comentarios en el código son buenas prácticas a la hora de compartir el código.
- pruebe su código en una nueva sesión R vacía para asegurarse que el código es ejecutable. Muchas veces no nos damos cuenta al compartir un código que ya tenemos inicializadas ciertas variables, probar el código a compartir en una nueva sesión nos hara darnos cuenta de esto. La gente debería ser capaz de copiar y pegar sus datos y su código en la consola y obtener exactamente lo mismo que usted tiene.

### Dar información adicional

En la mayoría de los casos, sólo la versión de **R** y el sistema operativo serán suficientes. Cuando surgen conflictos con los paquetes, dar la salida de **`sessionInfo()`** puede ser de gran ayuda. Cuando se habla de conexiones a otras aplicaciones (ya sea a través de ODBC o cualquier otra cosa), también se deben proporcionar números de versión para éstas, y si es posible también la información necesaria en la configuración.

Si está ejecutando **R** en **RStudio** usar **`rstudioapi::versionInfo()`** puede ser útil para reportar su versión de **RStudio**.

Si tiene un problema con un paquete específico, puede que quiera proporcionar una versión del paquete dando la salida de **`packageVersion("nombre del paquete")`**.

### [Reprex](https://github.com/tidyverse/reprex)

Este paquete que puedes instalar a demanda con `install.packages("reprex")` o bien, si usas `Rstudio` ya lo tienes incorporado como un `addin`, hace algo muy simple y tremendamente útil. Digamos que tienes un código como el siguiente:

```
plot(runif(100))
```

Lo seleccionas, lo copias al portapapeles e invocas a `reprex::reprex()` o bien en `Rstudio` vas a `Addins -> Reprex selection` y mágicamente generará el código completo para pegar como ejemplo , por ejemplo aquí en SOes.

````
``` r
plot(runif(100))
```

![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaqDu.png)

<sup>Created on 2019-05-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>
````

Lo que terminaría siendo:

```r
plot(runif(100))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-05-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>