# Como calcular el Cp de Mallows

Tags: r

Me encuentro en un inconveniente, estoy tratando de calcular el Cp de Mallows para diferentes regresiones lineales (cada regresión tiene un número diferente de variables independientes), pero cuando intento usar el paquete `leaps()` me envía un error

> Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c(as.character(1:9),
>   LETTERS)[1:NCOL(x)]) :    attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with
>   less than two dimensions

No sé como corregirlo. Además, no sé como definir variables variables X para que el software R pueda calcular el coeficiente Cp. No tengo un conocimiento avanzado del software, ya apenas estoy aprendiendo a usar el programa.

```
data = read.table('clipboard')
names(data)

y=datos$V1
x1=datos$V2
x2=datos$V3
x3=datos$V4
x4=datos$V5
x5=x1*x2
x6=x1*x3
x7=x1^2
x8=x2^2
x9=x3^2
x10=x4^2

m.general=lm(y~x1+x2+x3+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7+x8+x9+x10) 
summary(m.general) 
best=regsubsets(y~x1+x2+x3+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7+x8+x9+x10,datos,nb‌​est=3) 
summary(best)
m.r1=lm(y~x5,datos)
summary(m.r1)
AIC(m.r1)
press(m.r1)
x=data$V6
y=data$V1
m.r1Cp=leaps(x,y,method=c("Cp","adjr2","rsq"))
```

Comment: Bienvenido, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y veas [ask], no uses los comentarios para agregar información, edita la pregunta desde el botón [edit], acabó de agregarte el código de todas formas. Hay un concepto en SO que es el de [mcve], la idea es la de compartir código y datos que nos permitan a los que estamos del otro lado, reproducir exactamente el problema que mencionas, en el caso de tu pregunta, faltarían los datos para reproducir la misma situación. Saludos.

Comment: Revisa este enlace para ver como construir un ejemplo reproducible en R: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/109438/que-tener-en-cuenta-en-r-para-construir-un-ejemplo-reproducible/109439#109439.

Answer (score 1):

Voy a responderte puntualmente por el error, al no contar con los datos es complicado entender que es lo que buscas. Según la documentación del paquete `leaps`, la función `leaps()` espera que el parámetro `x` sea: `A matrix of predictors` y claramente en tu ejemplo pareciera que no lo es, ya que le estás indicando `data$V6` el cual si bien es una columna, de la forma en que lo estás indicando se "promueve" a un vector.

Algunas posibles soluciones:

- Estas definiendo mal el parámetro `x`, se supone que para evaluar modelos este valor debiera al menos tener dos variables predictoras, no tiene sentido evaluar un modelo con una única variable predictora, creo que el problema pasa por esto, para agregar variables, simplemente haces algo así: `x <- data$[c("V5","V6")]`.
- Podrías de todas formas resolver el error forzando algunas cosas en tu código de la siguiente forma:

  ```
  x=data$[c("V6")] <- Con esto al menos mantenemos el tipo de dato original
  m.r1Cp=leaps(x=x,y=y,method=c("Cp","adjr2","rsq"),strictly.compatible=FALSE)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Deberías poner un ejemplo reproducible de tus datos, así podríamos ayudarte de forma más sencilla. En principio parece que estas intentando asignarle un vector a colnames (es decir, el nombre de las variables que van por columnas) más largo que el número de columnas que tiene ese data frame.

Espero que te ayude! Un saludo!

Comment: Hola Tito, este es el código que estoy usando, de pronto al verlo sepas cual es el error: 

data = read.table('clipboard')

names(data)

y=datos$V1

x1=datos$V2

x2=datos$V3

x3=datos$V4

x4=datos$V5

x5=x1*x2

x6=x1*x3

x7=x1^2

x8=x2^2

x9=x3^2

x10=x4^2

m.general=lm(y~x1+x2+x3+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7+x8+x9+x10)

summary(m.general)

best=regsubsets(y~x1+x2+x3+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7+x8+x9+x10,datos,nbest=3)

summary(best)

m.r1=lm(y~x5,datos)

summary(m.r1)

AIC(m.r1)

press(m.r1)

x=data$V6

y=data$V1

m.r1Cp=leaps(x,y,method=c("Cp","adjr2","rsq"))

Comment: El cambio entre data y datos es intencionado? Tal vez te esté dando el problema... Fíjate que primero copias los datos del "clipboard" y le asignas la variable data, después datos$V1 tiene asignado la variable datos... Además intenta no copiar valores del clipboard pues dependerá de los datos que tengas copiados... Otro consejo y este es más de estilo que otra cosa, es que trates de acostumbrarte a usar "<-" en vez de "=".

Comment: Lo siento, data y datos corresponde a la misma base de datos, escribí esto mismo en la stackoverflow en su versión en inglés y quise cambiar el nombre de "datos" por "data", pero en mi código todo lo tengo "datos".

Comment: ¿Como puedo extraer valores de una tabla de excel para no usar el clipboard?

Comment: En uno de los cuatro paneles que tienes en RStudio en la ficha enviroment >> import dataset >> From Excel. Esta es la manera más fácil, aunque hay otras formas.