# Asignar diferentes símbolos en una gráfica

Tags: r, ggplot2

Quiero hacer un plot de mis muestras y asignar un símbolo distinto acorde con el tipo de especie que sea. 
Los paquetes que he usado son:
         library(vegan)
         library(reshape2)
Los script que he realizado para la gráfica han sido:
partiendo de un extracto del dataframe que tiene

```
        Datraframe
        Site      Date    Habitat    Season    Year     Taxa
        Q1F    08_09_2015  Oak     Autumn   2015-2016   Adonis_flammea
        E2F    08_09_2015  Oak     Autumn   2015-2016   Agrimonia_eupatoria
        Q4F    08_09_2015  Oak     Autumn   2015-2016   Ajuga_chamaepitys
        L1P    08_09_2015  Oak     Autumn   2015-2016   Ajuga
```

la convierto en una matriz:

```
        Matrix_Rawdata<-acast(Datos,Site~Taxa,fill = 0 )
        Matrix_Rawdata<-data.frame(Matrix_Rawdata)
```

El dataframe Matrix_Rawdata es el siguiente:
            dput(head(Matrix_Rawdata))

```
     Adonis_flammea Agrimonia_eupatoria    Ajuga_chamaepitys Ajuga     
Q1F      1                0                      0             0
E2F      0                1                      0             0       
Q4F      0                0                      1             0    
L1P      0                0                      0             1
```

y otro dataframe llamado Site, que tiene:

```
       Plot   Group
       Q1F     1
       E2F     2
       Q4F     1
       L1P     3
```

intento plotearlo usando estos scripts:

```
        DCA.Rawdata <- decorana(Matrix_Rawdata)
        plot(DCA.Rawdata,
             choices = c(1, 2),
             origin = TRUE,
             display = "sites",
             type = "n",
             cex = 0.5,
             main = "Raw Data",
             xlab = "DCA1 (0.353)",
             ylab = "DCA2 (0.247)")

        points (DCA.Rawdata, col = Site$Group, pch = Site$Group)
```

pero la parte de pch del script points me da este error:

```
        Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) : símbolo de gráfico inválido
```

¿Podrían decirme dónde está mi fallo?

Comment: Con R base es un poco complejo lograr lo que deseas, pero si decides usar `ggplot2` es una tarea bastante sencilla

Comment: ¿Podría darme un ejemplo para hacerlo con ggplot?

Comment: Claro, añade a la pregunta un extracto de tu `data.frame` para poder fabricar un ejemplo con tus datos. Para ello puedes usar el comando `dput(head(Dataframe,20))`

Comment: Ya he puesto un extracto de mi dataframe, no obstante no puedo poner todo pues es un datraframe bastante extenso

Comment: Adrián, el ejemplo que has indicado corre perfectamente bien usando alguno de los datos ya incluidos en el paquete `vegan`, por lo que me imagino que el tema pasa por los datos, trata de armar un dataframe más pequeño pero que produzca el error y publicalo tal como te indico Aldo, `dput(head(Datos,20))`, esto no copia todo el dataframe solo las primeras 20 filas. Por otro lado, me llama la atención que el mensaje de error este en castellano, lo has traducido tu?

Comment: Por favor revisar https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/109438/que-tener-en-cuenta-en-r-para-construir-un-ejemplo-reproducible

Comment: Hola Patricio, he intentado editar y poner un pequeño extracto de mi dataframe pero es absolutamente imposible. Contacto contigo por gmail por si existe otra posibilidad de encontrar el error. Respecto al mensaje de error es en castellano la segunda parte, no lo he modificado.

Comment: Adrián, revisa la clase de `Site$Group`, mediante `class(Site$Group)`, estuve revisando el código base de `graphics` y la única posibilidad que veo es que el tipo de dato de este parámetro no sea alguno de los aceptados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adrián, creo que el problema como te lo comenté, tiene que ver con el tipo de datos de `Site$Group`, posiblemente sea un `factor` un dato que no es de los que están permitidos para el parámetro `pch`. Podrías evitar el error haciendo:

```
points (DCA.Rawdata, col = Site$Group, pch = as.integer(Site$Group))
```

De esta forma fuerzas que el factor se convierta en un entero el cual se "mapea" a alguno de los símbolos gráficos disponibles, o bien puedes forzar el dato a un caracter, mediante `pch = as.character(Site$Group)`, en cuyo caso se dibujara dicho valor.

Comment: Patricio ¡estas en lo correcto! Funciona a la perfección. Muchas gracias