# Dividir gráfico en dos partes para poder visualizar mejor los datos

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo una consulta, tengo el código de una gráfica que quiero separarlas en dos debido a la gran cantidad de datos no se entiende. quisiera ver la mitad de estos resultados en una gráfica y la otra mitad en otra.

```
Medellin7 <- Medellin4 %>%
  filter(Medellin4$AÑO_T %in% c("2019"))
Medellin7
Medellin8 <- Medellin7 %>%
  filter(Medellin7$MES_TURNO %in% c("06"))
Medellin8

ATENCIONFUNCIONARIO <- Medellin8 %>%
  group_by(NOMBRE_SERVICIO, NOMBRE, NOMBRE_SERVICIO) %>%
  summarize(TIEMPO = mean(TIEMPO)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(NOMBRE_SERVICIO = factor(NOMBRE_SERVICIO, levels = unique(NOMBRE_SERVICIO)),
         NOMBRE = as.factor(NOMBRE))

grafico5 <- ggplot(data = ATENCIONFUNCIONARIO, 
                   aes(x = NOMBRE_SERVICIO, y = TIEMPO, group = NOMBRE, colour = NOMBRE)) + 
  xlab("SERVICIO") + ylab("CANTIDAD") +
  ggtitle("TIEMPO PROMEDIO ATENCIÓN FUNCIONARIO")+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "white"))+  
  geom_line(lwd=1)
grafico5
```

EJEMPLO DE LO QUE QUIERO LOGRAR

```
DEMANDADIATRAMITE1 <- DEMANDADIATRAMITE %>%
  group_by(NOMBRE_SERVICIO) %>%
  summarise(TIEMPO = round(mean(TIEMPO)))
DEMANDADIATRAMITE1 <- DEMANDADIATRAMITE1[order(DEMANDADIATRAMITE1$TIEMPO, decreasing = TRUE),]

write.csv (DEMANDADIATRAMITE1, "DEMANDADIATRAMITE1.csv")


# Grafico Horizontal tiempo Promedio por actividad

p7 <-ggplot(DEMANDADIATRAMITE1,aes(x= reorder(NOMBRE_SERVICIO,-TIEMPO),TIEMPO))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "#99FF33") +
  coord_flip() +
  ggtitle("DEMANDA PROMEDIO MES")+
  geom_text(aes (label = round((TIEMPO),1)), cex=2 , nudge_x = 0, color = "Black", )+
  ylab("Tiempo (min)")+xlab("")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1)) +
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "gray"))
p7

p8 <- p7 +  scale_x_discrete(breaks = DEMANDADIATRAMITE1$NOMBRE_SERVICIO[1:20]) + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1, 20))
p10 <- p7 +  scale_x_discrete(breaks = DEMANDADIATRAMITE1$NOMBRE_SERVICIO[21:50]) + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(21, 50))
p8
p10
```

Como puedes ver se grafican los primeros 20 datos en una gráfica y los otros restantes en otra gráfica, pero al utilizar este código con esta gráfica no me divide las graficas correctamente.

Comment: Si no cargas/subes un ejemplo reproducible (por ejemplo: [ejemplo1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/109438/qu%C3%A9-tener-en-cuenta-en-r-para-construir-un-ejemplo-reproducible), [ejemplo2][2]) es muy dificil poder ayudarte.<br>
Tampoco es claro si quieres "partir" en dos el grafico que muestras o si quieres cada codigo en un panel diferente. [2]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Hola Lina, no entiendo muy bien tu pregunta. ¿El gráfico de arriba es el que quieres dividir en dos grupos? Por empezar, me resulta raro que uses un gráfico de líneas con un eje `x` que no representa una línea de tiempo (¿puede ser un error o fue esa la intención?), en esto es más lógico el gráfico de barras de más abajo.