# Contar valores únicos de un string

Tags: r, string, filtro

Mi intención sería poder averiguar, por cada uno de los destinos que provee el data set de "flights" perteneciente al paquete "nycflights13", la cantidad de compañías distintas que llegan a ellos. 
Para ello, primero definí la siguiente variable:

```
flights%>%
  filter(!is.na(dep_delay), !is.na(arr_delay)) -> not_cancelled
```

Y luego quise agrupar los datos por destino y filtrarlos por aquellos a los cuales llegaran más de dos compañías, de la siguiente manera:

```
not_cancelled %>%
  group_by(dest) %>%
  arrange(dest) %>%
  summarise(tot_carriers = count(carrier))
```

Este código me arroja error dado que no puede utilizarse summarise sobre un objeto de clase character. Pero sin embargo, no sé cómo lograr contar los casos únicos.

Comment: No me queda clara tu intención. ¿Es posible que subas un ejemplo de dataset con una variable y unos cuatrocasos e indicar cuál sería el resultado que esperas?

Comment: Bienvenido asteriks a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Revisa tambien como hacer un [mcve] y https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/109438/qu%c3%a9-tener-en-cuenta-en-r-para-construir-un-ejemplo-reproducible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que buscas, lo puedes resolver mediante [`n_distinct()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/n_distinct.html) que cuenta los valores únicos de cada grupo:

```
flights %>%
  filter(!is.na(dep_delay), !is.na(arr_delay))  %>% 
  group_by(dest) %>%
  summarise(tot_carriers = n_distinct(carrier)) %>% 
  filter(tot_carriers >= 2) %>% 
  arrange(dest)
```