# ¿Cómo eliminar valores anómalos u outliers de un set de datos para una regresión multiple?

Tags: r, dataset

Estoy necesitando limpiar mi 'dataset' de algunos valores **anómalos** en mis variables para llevar adelante la **regresión** sobre una variable 'target'.

Comment: Especifica tu pregunta, puedes agregar:

* Una base de datos. 
* Vectores. 

Si deseas recomendaciones sobre métodos, está el test de grubbs o el criterio de Chauvenet. Pero sin una base de datos no hay forma de como ayudarte.

Comment: Revisa como hacer un [mcve] y https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/109438/qu%c3%a9-tener-en-cuenta-en-r-para-construir-un-ejemplo-reproducible, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Es importante notar que la presencia de valores anómalos en una variable no significa que deban removerse de manera automática porque podría perderse información valiosa. Pero si ayuda con tu modelo, aquí hay un método que difundió hace poco [R-bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-remove-outliers-in-r/) que utiliza el rango intercuartiles (IQR).

```r
# se debe tener la variable en forma de vector
variable <- df$variable

# identificar cuartiles y rango intercuartil
Q <- quantile(variable, probs=c(.25, .75), na.rm = FALSE)
iqr <- IQR(variable)

up <-  Q[2]+1.5*iqr # Rango superior  
low <- Q[1]-1.5*iqr # Rango inferior

# filtrar valores dentro del rango
eliminated<- subset(df, variable > low & variable < up)
```