# Crear una variable politómica basada en una variable ya existente

Tags: r, variables

Lo que sucede es que soy nuevo en R y estoy intentando correr un modelo logit multinomial. Necesito crear mi variable dependiente con 5 categorías, sin embargo, no he podido. En la base de datos ya hay una variable creada con valores de 1 a 10. Lo que quiero es crear otra reducida con 5 categorías, pero con nombres. Por ejemplo, que ExtIzq= 1,2. Estuve revisando y al parecer podría crear la variable mediante la función mutate(), sin embargo, no sé si en realidad no va al caso o que estoy escribiendo el código mal. Cabe añadir que la variable está convertidad en factor.

Agradezco la ayudaa!!!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, bienvenido al sitio. Las preguntas que no muestra ningún trabajo previo, no suelen ser bien recibidas. Por favor, añade lo que has intentado y el error que has obtenido. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola! Te agradezco el consejo! Ya lo corregí. Saludos :)

Comment: Hola Maicol25, entiendo la pregunta y me gustaría ayudarte, sin embargo me quedan algunas dudas ¿cual es la variable que tiene valores del 1 al 10? (supongo que Ideo, y también supongo que Elecciones es un data.frame). Para poder ayudarte mejor me gustaría que me ayudaras con esas dudas. Un par de sugerencias es que uses el editor de código de la pagina para compartir tus avances en lugar de una imagen.  Por último te sugiero que leas la respuesta de Patricio que te ayudara a crear un [ejemplo reproducible de R](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/109439/61530)