# Determinar umbrales (máx y mín) en varibles meteorológicas

Tags: r

Tengo una serie de datos de media hora de aproximadamente 15 años, de los cuales deseo establecer un rango o umbral máximo y mínimo. Todos los datos que estén fueran del umbral deberán ser eliminados. Estos umbrales servirán como referencia para datos futuros en los cuales si no cumple con el umbral establecido serán limpiados o eliminados.

Quisiera saber si existe algún o algunos métodos para determinar los umbrales máximo y mínimo para una serie de datos.

Comment: ¿Será que buscas algo como `range()?. Podrías añadir un ejemplo a tu pregunta?

Comment: Hola Daniela , el rango de datos los necesitas sobre el todo el set de datos o lo tienes que agrupar por alguna variable , ejemplo el día, hora etc.

Comment: No necesito agruparlos, es para todo el set de datos... Diciéndolo en otras palabras necesito establecer un limite superior e inferior para todos los datos. Y los que queden fuera de los límites deberán ser eliminados...

Answer (score 0):

Como Patricio dijo puede usar `range()` o usar `min()` y `max()`.

Supone que tiene datos como asi

```
fechas <- sample(seq(as.POSIXlt("1990-12-01 1:00:00"), 
                     as.POSIXlt("2000-12-01 1:00:00"), by="hour"), 
                 100)
```

Entonces, puede determinar umbrales con

```
max(fechas)
[1] "1999-09-05 17:00:00 CDT"
```

```
min(fechas)
[1] "1990-12-10 22:00:00 CST"
```

```
range(fechas)
[1] "1990-12-10 22:00:00 CST"
[2] "1999-09-05 17:00:00 CDT"
```

Y luego cuando quiera eliminar datos afuera del rango, puede usar `filter()` de `dplyr`. Voy a adivinar los datos son en un tibble llamada `data` con una columna llamada `fechas` (por lo general es mejor que des un ejemplo

```
max_fecha <- max(fechas)
min_fecha <- min(fechas)


data %>%
   filter(fechas >= min_fecha, fechas <= max_fecha))
```

o

```
data %>%
   filter(between(fechas, min_fecha, max_fecha))
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero lo que necesito no es simplemente determinar el valor máximo o mínimo ya que siendo así todos los datos entrarían en el rango y ninguno sería eliminado. Lo que necesito es saber que datos podrían ser valores atípicos u outliers...

Comment: Ayudaría si hagas una ejemplo con datos falsos y más mejor si sea un ejemplo reproducible como asi https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/109438/qu%c3%a9-tener-en-cuenta-en-r-para-construir-un-ejemplo-reproducible. ... pero es algo como tienes 1000 datos de POSIXlt y quieres saber caul son muy lejos del otros? Depende como definir que son outliers. Por ejemplo puedes convirtir los fechas a segundos después de 1970 y usa el método de rango intercuartil. pero no pienso que tiene mucho sentido en este caso. Quizas es mejor que haces un ggplot y ves si y valores atípicos?