# Añadir columnas a un data frame de R si estan en otro data frame y que clasifique el valor de dicha columna

Tags: r, rstudio

Dispongo de un dataset de  variables: x1, x2, x3, x4 y x5, cuyos valores oscilan entre 1 y 5
df <-data.frame(matrix(sample(1:5,25,replace = TRUE), ncol=5))

En otro data frame tengo el nombre de las variables que pueden ser 1 o más de esas. Supongamos que tengo X2 y X4 y quiero que atomaticamente me cree las columnas x2_rec y X4_rec y que cuando los numeros sean 4 o 5 en las columnas X2 y X4 lo transforme en 1 en X2_rec y X4_rec (sino un 0).

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Te sugiero que intentes agregar a tu pregunta, un [mcve], también puede serte útil: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/109438/qu%c3%a9-tener-en-cuenta-en-r-para-construir-un-ejemplo-reproducible

Answer (score 0):

Podes hacerlo con una for loop facil:

```
for(col in df1$nombres){
    nuevo <- paste0(col, "_rec")
    df[[nuevo]] <- ifelse(df[[col]] %in% c(4,5), 1, 0)
}

print(df)

  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X2_rec X4_rec
1  4  4  3  4  2      1      1
2  5  4  3  2  3      1      0
3  5  1  2  3  4      0      0
4  3  2  2  4  1      0      1
5  2  3  5  5  3      0      1
```

---

**Datos de muestra**

```
# ejemplo
df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:5,25,replace = TRUE), ncol=5))

# dataframe tiene nombres
df1 <- data.frame(nombres = c("X2", "X4"))
```