# BuscarV o Vlookup aplicado en R

Tags: r, excel

Quisiera pedir su ayuda para saber como utilizar una función similar a BuscarV o Vlookup, pero en R. Tengo una matriz de valores únicos de nx1 (donde la columna es mi cliente) y quiero ponerle una segunda columna (en esa misma matriz), con su alias. El cruce es con base en una matriz de n+3000 x 10. Ya lo he intentado con "merge" y "join", pero en lugar de dejarme mi matriz de nx1 (rellenando los valores únicos con su alias), me da una matriz de n +3000 x 10.
Ojalá alguien pudiera orientarme, muchas gracias!!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido @EmilioSaldaña. Lo ideal sería que en lugar de pegar un recorte del Excel incluyeras en tu pregunta ejemplos reales y reproducibles de los data.frame con los que estás trabajando. En `R` con `dput(head(df1))` obtienes el código que hace que el data.frame sea reproducible en cualquier computadora. Puse una respuesta más abajo, sin embargo al tener que simular los datos no me es posible saber si resolverá tu problema.

Comment: muchas gracias @mpaladino !!! Gracias por tomarte el tiempo de leer, explicarme y resolverme. Fíjate que si había intentado con left_join, pero pequeño detalle que creí que no interferiría, es que mi df2, tiene más de 2 columnas. Tiene 5 en total, con ventas, ubicación, semana... entonces, al querer aplicar la función, me daba una matriz muy grande. Ahora, dejando solo las 2 columnas de cliente y alias, jala bien, pero repite algunos clientes. Viendo la data, esto es porque le pusieron 2 "alias" distintos, al mismo cliente. Gracias!!

Comment: Te agradezco de nuevo el apoyo y disculpa que no subí la data, la verdad no sabía como hacerlo.

Comment: Podrías editar la pregunta y mejorarla agregando un ejemplo mínimo reproducible. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/109438/qu%C3%A9-tener-en-cuenta-en-r-para-construir-un-ejemplo-reproducible/ es una excelente referencia al respecto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respuesta corta:

```
dplyr::left_join(df1, distinct(df2), by = "cliente")
```

Respuesta larga:

Para evitar que haga múltiples match puedes usar la función `dplyr::distinct()`. De ese modo el data.frame de la derecha tendrá solamente una ocurrencia de cada combinación de valores en filas. Así un simple `left_join()` resuelve el problema.

Quizás el código sea más claro que mi explicación. Empiezo por simular unos datos similares a los que presentas en la imagen.

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 <- tibble(
  cliente = sample(c("Cliente del Oeste", "Cliente del Este"), 
                   size = 10, 
                   replace = TRUE),
  alias = str_extract(cliente,"(\\w+)$"))

df1 <- tibble(
  cliente = sample(c("Cliente del Oeste", "Cliente del Este"), 
                   size = 5, 
                   replace = TRUE))
```

Así se ve `df1`

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   cliente           alias
   <chr>             <chr>
 1 Cliente del Oeste Oeste
 2 Cliente del Este  Este 
 3 Cliente del Oeste Oeste
 4 Cliente del Oeste Oeste
 5 Cliente del Oeste Oeste
 6 Cliente del Oeste Oeste
 7 Cliente del Oeste Oeste
 8 Cliente del Oeste Oeste
 9 Cliente del Oeste Oeste
10 Cliente del Este  Este
```

Y así se ve `df1`, que no tiene la columna `alias`. Si estuviera no sería tan complicado el problema, solo que el `alias` aparecería como `alias.y`.

```
# A tibble: 5 x 1
  cliente          
  <chr>            
1 Cliente del Este 
2 Cliente del Este 
3 Cliente del Este 
4 Cliente del Oeste
5 Cliente del Este
```

Si usas `left_join(df1, df2, by = "cliente")` va a haber un match cada vez que haya una coincidencia en la columna cliente en el df de la izquiera y el de la derecha. Como `Cliente del Este` está muchas veces en el df de la derecha va a haber múltiples match, lo mismo con `Cliente del Oeste`. Para evitarlo puedes usar `distinct(df2)`.

```
distinct(df2)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  cliente           alias
  <chr>             <chr>
1 Cliente del Oeste Oeste
2 Cliente del Este  Este
```

Ahora tienes solo una ocurrencia de cada combinación única en las filas.

Entonces

```
left_join(df1, distinct(df2), by = "cliente")
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  cliente           alias
  <chr>             <chr>
1 Cliente del Este  Este 
2 Cliente del Este  Este 
3 Cliente del Este  Este 
4 Cliente del Oeste Oeste
5 Cliente del Este  Este
```

Creo que resuelve tu problema.

> PD: hay otra solución muy simple y complicada a la vez.

Revisando en `SO` en inglés si había una solución más eficiente me encontré con [esta joya](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64253446/5839337) del usuario akrun, que adapto a este problema:

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(alias = deframe(df2)[cliente])
```

Lo que hace es usar `deframe` para convertir a `df2` en un vector nombrado. Lo que era la primera columna serán los nombres, lo que era la segunda columna será el vector propiamente dicho. Al usar `[cliente]` dentro de la llamada de `mutate` encuentra ese nombre como columna del data.frame `df1` y al estar usando `[]` lo que hace igualar los nombres del output de `deframe` con los valores de la columna cliente. Para ver lo que pasa fuera del `mutate` hay que llamar explícitamente a `df1$cliente`.

```
deframe(df2)[df1$cliente]
```

Es una maravilla la mezcla de tidyverse con R base.

Comment: De nuevo, muchas gracias @mpaladino! Intenté la última opción que me pusiste, y jaló de maravilla. Solo por el tema de que son más de 2 columnas, me arroja un warning, dado que x, o en este caso df2, debería ser de 1 o 2 columnas.

Comment: `deframe()` espera dos columnas, una para los nombres y otra para los elementos del vector que crea. Si hay más de dos emite un warning avisando que descarta las siguientes columnas. Lo ideal sería seleccionar antes para evitar sorpresas y pasarle a `deframe()` solo esas dos columnas en el orden correcto. De todos modos si las dos primeras columnas de `df1` son las correctas el resultado va a ser el mismo.

Comment: Con respecto a los joins, son muy potentes porque admiten muchas modalidades. Por eso mismo son complicados. A mí me resulta de ayuda agregar un identificador único de fila (generalmete `1:n()`) para identificar más fácil las repeticiones/omisiones. Me facilita bastante entender que está pasando ahí adentro, validar el resultado y corregir problemas.