# Sintetizar dos columnas de fechas en una

Tags: r

Estoy trabajando en R. Tengo dos columnas que contienen fechas, y necesito quedarme con la más reciente en una nueva columna. Pero cuando lo hago, me aparece el formato numérico de la fecha y no lo puedo transformar. Qué me sugieren?

las variables son `MEDIDAS_FECHA` y `FECHA_Control`

```
base5$CONTROLRECOD<-ifelse(base5$MEDIDAS_FECHA>=base5$FECHA_Control,"MEDIDAS_FECHA","FECHA_Control")
base5$CONTROLRECOD1<-ifelse(base5$CONTROLRECOD=="MEDIDAS_FECHA",as.Date(base5$MEDIDAS_FECHA,format="%Y-%m-%d"),ifelse(base5$CONTROLRECOD=="FECHA_Control",as.Date(base5$FECHA_Control,format="%Y-%m-%d"),0))
```

eso me da como resultado un número que no logro convertir a fecha.

Comment: Hola Virginia, bienvenida a StackOverflow en español. Puse una respuesta a tu pregunta, sin embargo no estoy seguro de que funcione. Si agregas un ejemplo de los datos con los que estás trabajando siempre será más probable que obtengas una respuesta y sobre todo que la respuesta solucione el problema.  En https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/109438/qu%C3%A9-tener-en-cuenta-en-r-para-construir-un-ejemplo-reproducible/ hay una excelente guía al respecto. Bienvenida una vez más!

Answer (score 1):

Es un comportamiento normal del `ifelse()` aunque ciertamente resulta extraño y antinatural:

```
ret <- ifelse(TRUE, as.Date("2020-04-15"), as.Date("2020-04-15"))
ret
class(ret)

[1] 18367
[1] "numeric"
```

---

`ifelse()` se define como `ifelse(test, yes, no)` y según lo que se desprende de la documentación, el retorno es básicamente el vector `test` reemplazado los valores de `yes` o `no` según corresponda y coercionados de tal forma para que el resultado sea consistente con los valores de `yes` y luego los de `no`. En el caso de la fechas, lo que ocurre es una coerción entre un `logical` y un `Date`, dónde el resultado que satisface estos dos tipos de dato  es justamente  un `numeric`.

Para resolver el tema entre otras cosas podrías "rehacer" la clase original del resultado que esperas:

```
ret <- ifelse(TRUE, as.Date("2020-04-15"), as.Date("2020-04-15"))
class(ret) <- 'Date'
ret
class(ret)

[1] "2020-04-15"
[1] "Date"
```

---

Que en tu caso sería algo así:

```
base5$CONTROLRECOD1<-ifelse(base5$CONTROLRECOD=="MEDIDAS_FECHA",as.Date(base5$MEDIDAS_FECHA,format="%Y-%m-%d"),ifelse(base5$CONTROLRECOD=="FECHA_Control",as.Date(base5$FECHA_Control,format="%Y-%m-%d"),0))
class(base5$CONTROLRECOD1) <- 'Date'
```

Answer (score 0):

Dos opciones:

#### Convertir el número de días a una fecha

`ifelse` se toma algunas atribuciones al momento asignarle un tipo al output. En tu caso está convirtiendo la fecha a numérico, que son los días que pasaron entre la fecha y el origen, que en R es `1970-01-01`. En ese caso podrías volver a convertir ese número en fecha con `as.Date(fecha, origin = "1970-01-01")`.

Algo así:

```
base5$CONTROLRECOD<-ifelse(base5$MEDIDAS_FECHA>=base5$FECHA_Control,"MEDIDAS_FECHA","FECHA_Control")
base5$CONTROLRECOD <- as.Date(base5$CONTROLRECOD, origin = "1970-01-01")
```

No tengo los datos para verificarlo, pero creo que debería funcionar.

## Usar `dplyr::if_else`

La librería `dplyr` tiene una versión de `ifelse` que se llama `if_else` (nótese el guion bajo) que es más estable en el tipado. En este caso no coerciona a numérico a tu objeto de la clase fecha:

```
 library(dplyr)
 base5$CONTROLRECOD <- if_else(base5$MEDIDAS_FECHA >= base5$FECHA_Control, "MEDIDAS_FECHA", "FECHA_Control")
```

Si la respuesta no soluciona el problema recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta agregando un ejemplo de los datos con los que estás trabajando o haciendo precisiones para mejorar las respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias! unos genios!

Utilicé el if_else y me funcionó bárbaro. Luego pasé la fecha con as.Date:

```
library(dplyr)


base5$CONTROLRECOD<-if_else(base5$MEDIDAS_FECHA>=base5$FECHA_Control,base5$MEDIDAS_FECHA,base5$FECHA_Control)
base5$CONTROLRECOD<-as.Date(base5$CONTROLRECOD,format="%Y-%m-%d")`
```