# Crear una función de densidad de distribución uniforme en R

Tags: r, condiciones

Quiero hacer en R la formula de densidad de la distribución uniforme... Es un ejercicio, así no puedo usar `dunit()`.

La función tiene la siguiente forma:

f(x)=1/b-a,

Donde a < x < b, si no 0

He probado cosas con `if`, ... Pero mi nivel aún es bajo para sacarla, una mano? Mil gracias.

Ceci

Comment: Hola Ceciri! Por favor, dale una mirada a este post, sobre como elaborar la preguntas en SO: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/109438/qu%c3%a9-tener-en-cuenta-en-r-para-construir-un-ejemplo-reproducible. Seria valioso que incluyas lo que has intentado elaborar hasta ahora para facilitar entender los problemas que tienes al construir la función. Puedes esclarecer cuál es la función `dunit`?

Answer (score 0):

Una opción puede ser:

```
> dist_unif <- function(x, a = 0, b = 1) {
    if (a <= x && x <= b) {
        output  <- 1/(b - a)
        return(output)
    } else {
        return(0)
    }
}


> x = c(0:10)

> sapply(x, \(x) dist_unif(x, 1, 5))

[1] 0.00 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

El `if` tradicional es escalar, es decir solo puede verificar un única condición lógica, cuando quieres esto mismo aplicado a un vector, dispones del [`ifelse()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/ifelse), de acuerdo a tu definición podrías hacer algo así:

```
my_fun <- function(x, a, b) {
  ifelse(x > a & x < b,  # Condicion a verificar 
         1/(b - a),      # Retorno por TRUE
         0)              # Retorno por FALSE
}
```