# ¿Cómo defino una nueva categoría (Ns/Nr) para una variable ya existente?

Tags: r

La nueva categoría toma el valor de otra variable ya creada.
Estoy tratando de replicar una sintaxis de SPSS. Ahi me permite definir la varialbe nueva y luego agregarle la categoria de NR con los valores de otra variable.

Comment: Hola Daniel! Por favor dale una mirada a este post sobre creación de ejemplos reproducibles: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/109438/qu%c3%a9-tener-en-cuenta-en-r-para-construir-un-ejemplo-reproducible .Sería muy valioso que incluyeras una muestra de tus datos o un ejemplo basado en datos similares a los tuyos para facilitar que tu pregunta sea reproducida por otras personas. Para eso puedes usar la función dput() sobre una parte de tus datos, por ejemplo: dput(head(datos))

Comment: Gracias Jose!!! Lo voy a mirar y completar con los datos. Es la primera vez que hago una pregunta y no tuve muy en cuenta como realizarla.